# How to serialize and deserialize Custom Lists with protobuf-net

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have a custom List which carries some attributes I need to serialize along with its containing items.

However, as soon as I add a ProtoContract attribute to my custom list, its items dont get serialized anymore.

Example:

```
    [ProtoContract]
    public class MyCollection : List<string> { 

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string MyAdditionalField;
   }
```

Is this not supposed to work out of the box?

The only possible workaround I can think of is using a surrogate for the custom list which contains a separate List which then contains all the data. However, we are dealing with quite a lot of custom Lists... so this would be an inefficient approach.

Thank you,
TH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In common with `XmlSerializer` and `TypeDescriptor` (and possibly `DataContractSerializer` - I haven't checked), there is a strong divide between *is* a list vs *contains* a list. If something is a list, it doesn't have values itself.

The preferred layout there would be to *either* have a list *or* values.

At the protocol level, there is simply no way of representing that, as this is just `repeated string {name} = {field}` - there is simply nowhere for `MyAdditionalField` to go.

(update); tested, and indeed `XmlSerializer` behaves the same:

```
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="
http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <string>abc</string>
  <string>def</string>
</ArrayOfString>
```

`DataContractSerializer` hated it more, throwing:

> Type 'MyCollection' is an invalid collection type since it has DataContractAttribute attribute.

Comment: Thank you, I will go with the surrogate approach then. Right now I am struggeling way more with the Issue 203 I posted earlier today on google code.

Comment: @TwinHabit - will look later, but am on "work" time at the moment